# Table adapter not defined

Tags: vb.net, dataset, tableadapter

I had a project which has a dataset and some table adapters. Everything was working fine until recently when I reopened the project it gave me an error about my Table Adapter not being defined and I can't understand why as it has been working all along.
The error is specifically in the `Designer.vb` class in my project. Error:
`Error  2   Type 'SMSResults.dbNetmanSMSDataSetTableAdapters.SMSTableAdapter' is not defined.   ...\frmResults.Designer.vb  30  34  SMSResults`

Comment: First things first, is that table adapter class defined?  It's being defined but reported by the compiler as not is a very different issue to it's not being defined.  Remember that we know NOTHING about your project other than what you tell us, so make sure you tell us ALL that is relevant.

Comment: I dragged the table to my form so as to create the Table Adapter,Dataset etc onto my form. When I opened the project it wasnt there so I redragged the table,the same table adapter shows up but still cant be accessed from within the code @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the benefit of anyone else who does this. I added a module to my project and I named it the same as the project namespace. A really dumb thing to do but i just didnt notice and it then looks for your types in the module rather than the project. I lost a day trying to work out wtf happened. I could roll back but you dont learn much like that. Renamed the module and it all works again. Be WARNED!!!